# Steam -> Dota 2 will not boot/launch

Tags: steam, system-monitor

Well, i can't play DOTA 2 (switched from WIN).

When i press Play on steam, it says it is launching and then it is running, no sign of DOTA at all, but system monitor, what only shows 2 processes running, in the included screenshot.[image: screenshot]

Comment: Open a terminal and run `steam` the steam ui will open, now run your game and see if any errors are shown, add them here. Also what is your GPU and do you have the drivers for it?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GknnFxHF for long log and one error message, i tought linux dosen't need drivers??

Comment: Yes it does use drivers, they are in the kernel already though for most things, so you don't have to install them but GPU is advanced hardware, to make the best use of Nvidia or AMD cards (to play a 3d game) you need the drivers created by them (proprietary drivers), you can find them in the app `additional drivers`.

Comment: ehh, well where i get drivers terminal says i have Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]

Comment: Simplest way is to open the application `additional drivers` it is preinstalled in all Ubuntus.

Comment: in the top comment :) Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]

Comment: ehh http://prntscr.com/bbhmwf

Comment: I don't think you want to here this but AMD dropped support for many of there radeon chips on Ubuntu http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04 https://linux.slashdot.org/story/16/03/09/2049232/ubuntu-drops-support-for-amds-catalyst-gpu-driver https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-16.04-Dropping-fglrx You may just be out of luck here.

Comment: According to the Steam log it has a bunch of issues (lines 8, 73,  that may impact the described situation and that you should fix. Their solutions are straight-forward or at leas easy to find on AU or Google if you search for the error message.